# How to get SSL to work in Rails on Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I just deployed my Rails 4 app on a VPS with Ubuntu, Unicorn and NginX.

For my app I need to use SSL, so I have this `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  force_ssl

  ...

end
```

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
        upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0; }

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name myapp.com;
                rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        server {
                listen 443;
                server_name myapp.com;
                root /home/rails/public;
                index index.htm index.html;

                ssl on;
                ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myapp.com.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp.com.key;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
                }

                location @app {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_pass http://app_server;
                 }
        }
}
```

Everything seems to be working OK. When a request for an `http` page comes, it gets forwarded to `https`, which is nice.

However, when trying to change the `locale` of the application in the browser (through the languages menu), I get this error message in the browser:

> Safari can't open the page `https://app_server/en/sessions/new`
>   because Safari can't find the server "app server"

In the URL it also says: `https://app_server/en/sessions/new`

What am I missing here?

I am fairly new to NginX, so maybe someone can help me out here?

Any general advice on how to enhance my code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Actual question is, why your application directs you to `app_server` instead of `myapp.com`. Look into your application's config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `proxy_pass http://app_server;` which set `Host` header to `app_server` by default. Add `proxy_set_header Host $host;`, so your application will get right `Host`.

```
location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. OK, I replaced my line with yours but now (after restarting NginX) the app won't work at all. I get "Safari can't open the page because there were too many redirects." What am I missing?

Comment: Replaced? You should add one more line.

Comment: BTW, why you added `proxy_redirect off`?

Comment: Ah yes, now everything works. Thank you! I am still at the beginning NginX-wise, so it wasn't clear to me that I should add rather than replace.

Comment: BTW, I removed `proxy_redirect off` and everything still works. So I guess I don't need it.

Comment: I'm quite sure, that without this line you did not have to ask this question. But providing real `Host` is always good thing.